# how to pull out a portion of an array and store it in a new array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big array that I need to split down into pieces 
There's around 180 **div**'s that contains content and images, each div having a class called **divcontent** and A button.

```
var extend_btn  = $('#extend');
var replace_btn = $('#replace');

extend_btn.click(function()
{
    //extend content
})

replace_btn.click(function()
{
    //replace content
})



$(document).ready(function()
{
  var divcontent = $('.divcontent');
  for (var i = 10; i < divcontent.length; i++) {
    divcontent[i].hide();
  }
})
```

Now I just need to extend the content when I click the extend_btn, 
and replace the content when when the replace button is pressed.

Comment: check out https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question content !!!

Comment: Check out [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)